# For loop issue in angualrjs and javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[image]

> Hi i have an array in this 7 object are present and 3 invertors, means
>   accoding to the data im getting columns correctly but columns are
>   wrong, how many invertors have been created on the particular date
>   those many should come. if that present day 2 inverotrs are 2 columns
>   should come dynamically... which i am not getting can any one help me out.

```
var url = "http://52.9.55.95:91/api/ExcelDetails/ExcelExportForLog?Sid=1&FromDt=2017-02-21&ToDt=2017-02-22"
console.log(url);
       var tabledata=[];
  $scope.inventorarray=[];
http({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url
    }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

           // $scope.loaded = true;
            $scope.data = data;
            $timeout(function () { $scope.loaded = true; }, 500);

            //console.log("reporting to data received : success");
            console.log(data);


        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          var tdata={
           "heading":"InvCount: "+i,
           "Date":data[i].TimeofReading.substring(0,10)
          }
          tabledata.push(tdata);
         }
         $scope.tablearray=tabledata;

  console.log($scope.tablearray)

        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          var Lastreadingkey=data[i].Lastreading;
          var Readingbykey=data[i].Readingby;
          debugger
        var tdata={
         "Lastreading":Lastreadingkey,
         "Readingby":Readingbykey
        }
        $scope.inventorarray.push(tdata);
       }

 console.log($scope.inventorarray)

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.loaded = false;
            swal({ title: "Warning!", text: "Something went wrong!", type: "warning", confirmButtonText: "OK" });
            $timeout(function () { $scope.loaded = true; }, 500);

            //console.log("reporting to data received : failure");
            //console.log(data);

        });
var url = "http://52.9.55.95:91/api/ExcelDetails/ExcelExportForLog?Sid=1&FromDt=2017-02-21&ToDt=2017-02-22"
console.log(url);
       var tabledata=[];
  $scope.inventorarray=[];
http({
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url
    }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.data = data;
            $timeout(function () { $scope.loaded = true; }, 500);
        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          var tdata={
           "heading":"InvCount: "+i,
           "Date":data[i].TimeofReading.substring(0,10)
          }
          tabledata.push(tdata);
         }
         $scope.tablearray=tabledata;

  console.log($scope.tablearray)

        for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
          var Lastreadingkey=data[i].Lastreading;
          var Readingbykey=data[i].Readingby;
          debugger
        var tdata={
         "Lastreading":Lastreadingkey,
         "Readingby":Readingbykey
        }
        $scope.inventorarray.push(tdata);
       }

 console.log($scope.inventorarray)

        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //$scope.loaded = false;
            swal({ title: "Warning!", text: "Something went wrong!", type: "warning", confirmButtonText: "OK" });
            $timeout(function () { $scope.loaded = true; }, 500);

        });

 $scope.tableToExcel=(function() {


     var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
       , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
       , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
       , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
     return function(table, name) {
       if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
       var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
       window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx))
     }
   })()
 }]);
```

myhtml page

```
<table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th ng-repeat="data in tablearray" colspan="2">{{data.heading}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Date</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="data in inventorarray"> <p ng-if="$index%2==0"> Last Reading</p><p ng-if="$index%2>0"> Read By</p> </td>
                </tr>
                <tr  ng-repeat="data in tablearray"> 
                    <td> {{data.Date}}</td>
                    <td ng-repeat="data in inventorarray"> <p ng-if="$index%2==0"> {{data.Lastreading}}</p><p ng-if="$index%2>0">{{data.Readingby}}</p> </td>
                 </tr>
            </table>
```

> can any let know the loop please im stuc here from past 2days.. i
>   need to be finish today please make fiddle and send me

Comment: hi i need to get my out put accoding my image. in my api at present each day only one inverter is present but that is also not correctly coming, let me know if more than one is present means how to do the loop.

Comment: yes i have tried... but doubt in loop only, but it check length in both row wise as well column wise... when only on invertor is present in the day then y it check the count, please check my loop

Comment: see bro i do have one data object in that seven objects are present